# Is there a way to async call external API without slowing down the entire website?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl

I have an e-commerce where I load eBay API at the end of the page with items related to the main product.

But I noticed that the request slows down the entire page load by 4 to 10 seconds.

I'd rather have the page loaded and THEN a module in the page with a loader, so by the time the user scrolls all the way down the eBay items are loaded. I know I could try this in JavaScript but, before coding it, I was wondering if PHP can handle asynchronous requests.

I'm currently using CURL. Here's my code:

```
$q = 'iphone'
$api     = 'https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&SECURITY-APPNAME=remoteco-effectsb-PRD-a38ccaf50-f6906249&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&keywords=';
$url     = $api . $q;

$ch      = curl_init();
$timeout = 1;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$output  = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$array   = (array) json_decode($output);
```

Comment: You have almost 8k rep, have been a member for six and a half years, and have been awarded 16 gold badges. By now you should know that you are expected to spend an appropriate amount of time and effort in presenting your questions.

Comment: I notice you always write tags in your question titles. Please do not do that.

Answer (score 1):

After PHP finishes rendering your page, you can't receive additional data from the same script.

You can start background tasks, but can't receive the result with the same request.

Your best option would be to move the code to fetch related items to another PHP script and call that with Javascript.

That said there are ways to [send chunked responses](http://www.phpied.com/progressive-rendering-via-multiple-flushes/) but are likely not the best  option for you.